# Zero linear transformation in limits with Euclidean norm

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

This does not seem too difficult, but I've been stuck here for a while. Could someone give me a hint?

Question: Let $A$ be a linear transformation on $R^n$. $v$ is a vector in $R^n$. Prove that if $\frac{||Av||}{||v||}\rightarrow0$ as $v\rightarrow 0$, then $A=0$. $||\cdot||$ denotes Euclidean norm.

My try: proof by contradiction. Suppose at least one element in $A$, namely $A_{pq}$, is nonzero. Ideally, the contradiction would be the limit of the above fraction is nonzero. The problem is the numerator always approaches zero as $v\rightarrow 0$. Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $v$ with $||v||\ne0$,
$$
||Av||=||v||\,\frac{||Av||}{||v||}=||v||\,\frac{||\lambda Av||}{||\lambda v||}=||v||\,\frac{||A(\lambda v)||}{||\lambda v||}
\to 0
$$
as $\lambda\to0$. Hence $Av=0$.

Comment: How did you take care of $||\lambda v||$ in the denominator when $v\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: $v$ is constant. Instead, $\lambda\to0$ and hence $\lambda v\to0$ and hence $||A(\lambda v)||/||\lambda v||\to 0$ and hence $||Av||=||v||\,||A(\lambda v)||/||\lambda v||\to 0$ as $\lambda\to0$. But $Av$ is independent of $\lambda$, so this can only happen if $||Av||=0$,